# Laravel 5.4.36 invalid input syntax for type date: "" LINE 5: ... b.date_out

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.4

Hello i am new laravel framework user and i need a help to know the cause of this error  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
LINE 5: ... b.date_out < '' OR

My Query:

```
   $available_rooms = DB::table('rooms as r')
                                    ->select('r.id', 'r.name')
                                    ->whereRaw("
                                    r.id NOT IN(
                                        SELECT b.room_id FROM reservations b
                                        WHERE NOT(
                                            b.date_out < '{$start_date}' OR
                                            b.date_in > '{$end_date}'
                                        )

                                        )
                                    ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the quotes in `whereRaw()`

**Try:**

```
$available_rooms = DB::table('rooms as r')
                                ->select('r.id', 'r.name')
                                ->whereRaw("
                                r.id NOT IN(
                                    SELECT b.room_id FROM reservations b
                                    WHERE NOT(
                                        b.date_out < '{$start_date}' OR
                                        b.date_in > '{$end_date}'
                                    )
                                ")
```

Comment: Sorry i edited my post... i missed to add the full code. i still receive the same error

Comment: can someone help me please ?